# Fetch post json, headers are sometimes gone

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, fetch

Im having a strange issue.
My logs are showing that occasionally, a post endpoint returns http 400, because the header object is empty. It seems like its the same user that has the problem.

I am not able to reproduce the issue locally, and the endpoint works for most of the time for most users.

```
export async function postJson<T>(
  url: string,
  jsonPayload: string,
  caller: string
) {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  const payload: RequestInit = {
    credentials: "same-origin",
    method: "post",
    headers: headers,
    body: jsonPayload
  };
  const response = await fetch(url, payload);
  if (response.ok) {
    //Testing for empty response
    const data = await response.text();
    if (data) {
      return <T>JSON.parse(data);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    throw new Error(
      `Url=${url} returned non-ok status: ${response.status}. Status text:${
        response.statusText
      }; caller=${caller}, payload=${JSON.stringify(payload)}`
    );
  }
}
```

The log is showing the payload object as

```
 payload={"credentials":"same-origin","method":"post","headers":{},"body":"...some json..."}
```

The useragent that gets the 400 is

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say "The log is showing the payload object as" do you mean your server's log? Or the text of the error being thrown in the code above? If the latter, note that `JSON.stringify` will **always** show an empty object for `Headers` ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/tjcrowder/v53ufhqg/)), because `Headers` has no `toJSON` method and an instance has no enumerable properties. So the "empty headers" theory may well be a red herring. What you need to do is look at what the *server* gets for these requests.

Comment: Error 400 ("Bad Request") could be a size thing. Is your client sending a particularly large request your server may not be configured to accept?